# Class Variables and initialisation time

Tags: ruby, thread-safety, jruby

If I create a class variable like so:

```
class Song
  @@plays = 0

  class << self

    def plays=( plays )
      @@plays += plays
    end

    def plays
      @@plays
    end

  end

end
```

An I have multiple threads accessing this class method and setting it in jruby:

```
t1 = Thread.new {st1 = Song.plays = 1}
t2 = Thread.new {st2 = Song.plays = 5}
t3 = Thread.new {st3 = Song.plays = 3}
```

Is it possible to have 2 threads initialise @@plays to 0 at the same time? At what stage in execution are class variables created?

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. There's no `Song#plays=`, instead you're creating this method as a class method on `Song`'s singleton class.

Comment: Fixed it up, I added .new by habit.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. `Song.singleton_class.plays=` would work, but this is probably not want you want.

Comment: I fixed it, but it does not act as expected.

Comment: You now have both, an instance method and a class method, i.e. `Song.singleton_class.plays=` and `Song.singleton_class#plays=`. The latter is equivalent to `Song.plays=`, but it doesn't call your method. Hint: remove either `class << self` or use `def plays=`.

Comment: I think I need to delete this question and start again. My example is too abstract from my actual problem im trying to solve. I have went with `def plays=`

Comment: Note that `attr_accessor` defines an *instance* variable and a getter method for that variable. Therefore it's returning `@plays`, not `@@plays`. You can remove `attr_accessor` and define your own getter: `def plays; @@plays; end`

Comment: The important part of the question is: Is it possible to have 2 threads initialise @@plays to 0 at the same time?

Comment: Of course, but your code should be valid nonetheless :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@@plays = 0` is set when Ruby evaluates your class definition. This should only happen once and before starting your threads.

The assignment method `plays=` on the other hand can be executed concurrently. You should therefore wrap it in a [`synchronize`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Mutex.html#method-i-synchronize) call, e.g.:

```
require 'thread'
require 'song'   # <- @@plays is set to 0 here

Song.plays #=> 0

semaphore = Mutex.new

t1 = Thread.new { semaphore.synchronize { Song.plays = 1 } }
t2 = Thread.new { semaphore.synchronize { Song.plays = 5 } }
t3 = Thread.new { semaphore.synchronize { Song.plays = 3 } }

[t1, t2, t3].each(&:join)
Song.plays #=> 9
```

Another option is to make `Song#plays=` thread-safe by moving the mutex into the `Song` class:

```
class Song
  @@plays = 0
  @@semaphore = Mutex.new

  def self.plays=(plays)
    @@semaphore.synchronize { @@plays += plays }
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Should I create the mutex in a class variable to ensure it is not created concurrently by 2 threads? Same question worded differently, how would you make the Song class thread safe?

Comment: @KieranAndrews yes, create the mutex just like `@@plays`, i.e. before starting your threads.

Comment: I doubt this answer the question. It does not anyhow ensure two threads would start with `@@plays == 0`. It can be set by an optional argument passed to `Thread.new`, however still miss the point what he would like to achieve.

Comment: @DavidUnric yes, several threads can start with `@@plays` (still) set to `0`. But only one thread can increment the class variable at a time.